# How to detect whether rspec tests were run in local or in Continuous Integration server ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The title basically says it all - I would like to detect whether the tests are being run on local machine or in CI?
(so I could re-run the test in case it fails for some reason in the CI.)

Comment: You can use an environment variable!

Comment: Nice. And what check to preform? I am hoping you haven't meant on `RAILS_ENV='test'`, as it would be a nonsense, as the `test` is in both cases.

Comment: Add a ENV variable on your CI. for example: `$ export CI=true`
Then check in your code with `ENV["CI"]`

Comment: Yes, @RaVen's comment is what I meant

Comment: Yes, but I can't read thoughts you know, @VanHuy . Ok, this could be a solution, but just wondering if there is a ore 'generic' way of doing this, as not all have always all the rights in the CI to set-up those variables. Is there a way to check which test server was created for the test, and to check it that way?

Answer (score 4):

There is a great article by Adam Johnson on the topic:

https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/03/09/detect-if-your-tests-are-running-on-ci/

> CI systems set various environment variables, so if you check for their presence you can tell if your code is running there.
> Here’s a list of some variables you can use for the most popular CI systems. (...)

**Azure Pipelines** sets `TF_BUILD` to `true` - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts&tabs=yaml#system-variables).
**Bamboo** sets `bamboo.buildKey` - [docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-variables-289277087.html#Bamboovariables-Build-specificvariables).
**Buildkite** sets `BUILDKITE` to `true` - [docs](https://buildkite.com/docs/pipelines/environment-variables).
**Circle CI** sets `CIRCLECI` to `true` - [docs](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#built-in-environment-variables).
**Cirrus CI** sets `CIRRUS_CI` to `true` - [docs](https://cirrus-ci.org/guide/writing-tasks/#environment-variables).
**CodeBuild** sets `CODEBUILD_BUILD_ID` - [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html).
**GitHub Actions** sets `GITHUB_ACTIONS` to `true` - [docs](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/using-environment-variables#default-environment-variables).
**GitLab CI** sets `GITLAB_CI` - [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html).
**Heroku CI** sets `HEROKU_TEST_RUN_ID` - [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci#immutable-environment-variables).
**Hudson** sets `BUILD_ID` - [docs](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_Hudson/Building_a_software_project).
**Jenkins** sets `BUILD_ID` - [docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables).
**TeamCity** sets `TEAMCITY_VERSION` - [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/predefined-build-parameters.html#PredefinedBuildParameters-ServerBuildProperties).
**Travis CI** sets `TRAVIS` to `true` - [docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables).

> Also, some systems like **Circle CI**, **GitHub Actions**, **GitLab CI**, **Heroku**, and **Travis CI** set the generic variables `BUILD_ID`, `CI`, and others.
> These are intended to be provider-agnostic ways of detecting if you’re running on a CI environment, but this idiom doesn’t seem very widely adopted, so I wouldn’t rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to figure out the host that is currently running the specs:

```
require 'socket'

Socket.gethostname
```

And base my decision on this.